# Image stitching for a panoramic view of a face

Tags: opencv, image-stitching

I'm trying to program (on OpenCV, C++) some code to stitch some images from a face (taken from different angles) and create a 2D panorama of the whole face.
Do you know where can I find some example code to do this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the OpenCV page you can find all the info you need for stitching:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html

Answer (score -1):

Here you find a helpful example, You may modify it up to your need.
http://feelmare.blogspot.fr/2013/11/opencv-stitching-example-stitcher-class.html